# Centering a H1 vertically with background image at 100%

Tags: css

I'm trying to get a H1 vertically center aligned within a div that has a background image.

I tried this method I found: https://jsfiddle.net/vdqdpyc0/12/

But found that the full height of the banner was only visible if I specifically added a px height to the div, or added padding to either element. This meant that when I resized, there was lots of white space above and below the banner. This wouldn't be an issue if the background was intended to repeat, but it isn't.

The end product needs to look [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4pUC1.jpg).

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.outer-wrapper {
  background: url("http://paulmason.name/media/demos/full-screen-background-image/background.jpg") no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
  max-height: 360px;
  height: 100%;
}

.inner-wrapper {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.header-wrapper {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

h1 {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-wrapper">
  <div class="inner-wrapper">
    <div class="header-wrapper">
      <h1>
        Vertically aligned text
      </h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I could go through reducing the padding for various responsive viewpoints, but I figured there has to be a more streamlined way of going about it.

Comment: to see the full height of the banner you can use `background-size: contain;` instead of `cover`; anyway, you'll get some padding at the two sides of the background banner

Comment: @LorenzoMarcon but then the image wouldn't be full width, right?

Comment: actually, what do you need.? you need multiple backgrounds to show.?? or you want the height to be 100% of the page?? can you be more clear.?

Comment: what was the problem explain detail

Comment: Wat do u want explain clearly, it helps to get the correct answer

Comment: @weBer - I don't need multiple backgrounds. Just the one. I've updated my initial post to include an image of what the banner needs to look like. Thanks.

Comment: @BharathKumar I've updated my post to include an image of what the final product should look like. Hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this much more easily these days with flexbox, e.g.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.outer-wrapper {
  background: url("http://paulmason.name/media/demos/full-screen-background-image/background.jpg") no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

h1 {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-wrapper">
  <div class="inner-wrapper">
    <div class="header-wrapper">
      <h1>
        Vertically aligned text
      </h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/0yxctLne/

Answer (score 0):

You can use a flexbox for this. [Here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) is a pretty simple guide to flexbox. For your issue, it should be enough to pass

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: center;
```

to the element surrounding the H1 tag, IF the surrounding element is the same height and width as the space you want the H1 tag to be centered in. This will define the main axis as vertical (read: column) and then center all content along the main axis. If you want, you can also add

```
align-items: center;
```

to have the text centered along the cross axis (as in horizontally).

Answer (score 0):

Do you need something like this? Flexbox is a nice way to do:

```css
.header-wrapper {
  background: url("http://paulmason.name/media/demos/full-screen-background-image/background.jpg") no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

h1 {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-wrapper">
  <div class="inner-wrapper">
    <div class="header-wrapper">
      <h1>
        Vertically aligned text
      </h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vdqdpyc0/20/)