# Text over image in h1

Tags: html, css, wordpress, overlay

What I'm trying to do, and don’t found exactly in the forum, is the following:

I have one image in top of my wordpress pages, and then an h1 with the title of the page. But I'd like to put the h1 just over the image, in the bottom and centered, defining another font, size, transparency, spaces between text lines and color (maybe creating a h1 class?).

The problem is all the solutions I have read, using div and css custom in my wordpress site, are not appropriate with adaptive modes. I mean, you have to fix a height, or the image will be adapted to the height or the text and it will be cut, but in mobile modes, where heights are always changing, it does not work well. Indeed, I will like to use different images in mobile: in desktop I will use a panoramic image, 940x470 pixels, but then display another image (I mean, the same but adapted to a square shape) with 800x800 pixels in mobile form.

This is what I've got now:

http://sientema-cp31.wordpresstemporal.com/viajar/fez-escapada/

```css
.texto-imagen {
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  line-height: 40px
}

.fondo-imagen {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-position: center center;
}

@media ( min-width:768px) {
  .fondo-imagen {
    min-height: 470px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="fondo-imagen" style="background-image:url(https://www.sientemarruecos.viajes/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/Escapada-a-Fez-desde-Tarifa-y-la-Costa-del-Sol-1.jpg)">
  <h1 class="texto-imagen">Escapada a Fez desde Tarifa y la Costa del Sol</h1>
</div>
```

Thanks a lot, because I have been reading solutions for two weeks, and I’m still lost.

Comment: I have forget to say it is important to show the entire image. I mean, I have read solutions using fixed heights and adapting the image in different solutions cutting the sides of the image, but it is not a solution for me.

Comment: I asked a very similar question a little while back - do any of the solutions here help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46951930/centering-a-h1-vertically-with-background-image-at-100

Comment: Also, you might have better luck tagging your question with HTML and CSS. Your current tags aren't really relevant to the issue you're having.

Comment: Thanks Sam, but the problem with that solution is that it "cuts" height and weight to adapt to different resolutions. I want the image to be shown in two resolutions: one fixed, for desktops (940x470) and one in square shape, using another image (maximum 800x800).

Comment: @rafaelinglesias hmm, I'm not sure how that could be done. If the background image must be fully visible at all times then the height would have to shrink as the screen does.

Comment: @SamJohnson, I'd try this solution then and try to improve it:
https://jsfiddle.net/0yxctLne/

But don't know why it doesnt work in my website:

http://sientema-cp31.wordpresstemporal.com/viajar/fez-en-tren/

Comment: maybe you can have a parent container with an img tag inside with your image and the text in an h1 tag. Set position relative to container and position absolute to the text with bottom: 0; left: 0; width: 100%;